# Degraded allocation. Consider increasing nursery-size if the warning persists

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin

I am getting the following message when opening a new screen I have added to my app

Warning: Degraded allocation. Consider increasing nursery-size if the warning persists.

Im assuming there is a build argument I can use to increase the nursery size. Does anyone know what the argument is and how to format it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably pinning too many objects, or using too many threads.

According to http://www.mono-project.com/Working_With_SGen#Nursery_Size you can set the `MONO_GC_PARAMS` environment variable to `nursery-size=8m` to double the nursery-size.

You set Environment variable for a xamarin.iOS project in Project Options > Run > General

Comment: Before invoking mono with your exe, place or enter export MONO_GC_PARAMS=nursery-size=8m in script or on command line.