# Warning: Degraded allocation. Consider increasing nursery-size if the warning persists

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin

I have suddenly the error in the subject but have no idea how to set this in VS2012.
Found this answer but dont get it exact how to adjust it:
[Degraded allocation. Consider increasing nursery-size if the warning persists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464295/degraded-allocation-consider-increasing-nursery-size-if-the-warning-persists)

This is my complete error code:

GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 0 num_hash_entries 0 sccs size 0 init 0.00ms df1 0.00ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.00ms setup-cb 0.00ms free-data 0.00ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
( 2042): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 50.59ms, total 50.64ms, bridge 0.08ms promoted 384K major 624K los 0K
( 2042): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 0 num_hash_entries 0 sccs size 0 init 0.00ms df1 0.00ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.00ms setup-cb 0.00ms free-data 0.00ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
( 2042): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 52.03ms, total 52.16ms, bridge 0.13ms promoted 0K major 624K los 0K
( 2042): Warning: Degraded allocation.  Consider increasing nursery-size if the warning persists.

Can somebody help me out on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bump up Monos GC nursery size by changing the [environment settings](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/environment/) for your application.

To do so, right click on your solution and add a text file called `environment.txt`. Then right click on this file, go to `Build Action` and set it to `AndroidEnvironment`.

[image]

In this file, add the following text:

```
MONO_GC_PARAMS=nursery-size=16m
```

This will configure the nursery size to 16 megabytes (which is huge). Here are some links that document this file:

- [`MONO_GC_PARAMS` arguments.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19375857/1099111)
- [Android build files.](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/environment/)

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for your answer, but I am using VS2012 is there anyway to do this with VS or with scripting or something?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I have tried to find out what this error generated and when I commented out "base.OnCreate(bundle);" the C# code started to run again without errors, so what and where does this nursery is being usefull for, only forms?

Comment: The nursery is a memory chunk reserved for garbage collection where small objects are allocated to initially. It isn't limited to forms, it holds all small allocations (like objects, arrays etc). I'm a bit too sleepy to explain it in-depth so I'd recommend reading the SGen docs for a thorough explanation of Monos garbage collection implementation. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/garbage-collector/sgen/

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, I read the doc already in the weekend however did not really understood the purpose. Than again I am new to android development ;) Thanks for your help, well appriciated